# How can i make my Help file(CHM) to be installed in the Folder where the user install my application

Tags: winforms, chm

I create a CHM file where user can have that when he click on F1. But what i need is how can i make that to be installed in the folder where the user install my application in such a way that when he click F1 i have to read that from the folder he installed and show it. And also how can i call in my application with out calling some thing as c:\sample.chm or some thing i need to call it from the directory where it was

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all i got the solution

```
  private void frmMain_HelpRequested(object sender, HelpEventArgs hlpevent)
    {
        string dirpath = string.Empty;
        string filename = "ACHWINAPP.chm";
        dirpath=System.Environment.CurrentDirectory;
        string[] files=new string[100];
        do
        {
            if (dirpath ==string.Empty || dirpath == Directory.GetDirectoryRoot(dirpath))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("no helpfile found");
            }
            else
            {
                files=Directory.GetDirectories(dirpath,"ACH");
                if (files.Length>0)
                {
                    //MessageBox.Show(files[0]);
                    string strHlp = string.Empty;
                    strHlp = files[0] + "\\ACHWINAPP.chm";
                    Help.ShowHelp(this, strHlp);
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    dirpath = Directory.GetParent(dirpath).ToString();
                }
            }
        } while (true);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To install the help file, you'll have to add it to your setup project so that it installs in the directory with your executable file.

Once you know the help file will be in your executable directory, you can drop a [HelpProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.helpprovider.aspx) onto your form. This will connect your help file to the F1 button. You will set `HelpNamespace` to the path of your help file. To dynamically figure out the path of your directory, you can use `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` to get the path of your executable and then add that to the name of your help file.

```
     string appPath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
     appPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(appPath);
     myHelpProvider.HelpNamespace = System.IO.Path.Combine(appPath, "myHelpFile.chm");
```

Comment: I need it from the directory not from executable location i will place my help file in my working folder like c:\Appname\sample.chm i would like to read from this location

Comment: Nice. Then set appPath = "whatever directory that your help file is in".

Comment: How can i blindly set it if i give my MSI to you you can install some where then how can i get that path